soy muy nuevo en el uso de visual studio, por accidente cerré la ventana de diseño, ahora solo puedo ver el código pero no la interface como la abro?
Al estar trabajando con el form en visual studio lo cerre pero ahora no se como abrirlo, disculpen que ponga lo mismo aqui, es mi primera vez preguntando

En el explorador de soluciones (donde está el árbol de archivos) haces doble click en él. Otra manera, es que cada form se divide en varios archivos (uno de ellos el diseño), si tu estas en alguno de los archivos de código haces click derecho y "Ver diseñador" (el primero de la lista). De forma análoga, si estas en el diseñador y quieres ver el código es lo mimo, pero ahora elijes "Ver Código"
